# Parametrizing a Curve in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Having a bit of trouble trying to parameterize the square with vertices at $\pm1$ and $\pm i $.

Do I treat each of the sides as an individual curve and view the whole square as a piece-wise?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

You want $z=x+iy$ to satisfy $|x|+|y|=1$ with real $x$ and $y$ seperately being both positive and negative

You could try something like $$z=\cos(t)|\cos(t)| + i \sin(t)|\sin(t)|$$

Alternatively, based on the polar expression $r = \frac{1}{| \cos(\theta)| + | \sin(\theta)|}$, you could try something like $$z= \frac{\cos(\theta)}{| \cos(\theta)| + | \sin(\theta)|} + i \frac{\sin(\theta)}{| \cos(\theta)| + | \sin(\theta)|} $$